How much time will a rod take to fall over

If a rod (pointed at one end) is carefully balanced on its point, how long will it take to fall over? Neglect all external disturbances and non-ideal effects.


The mass of the rod is $m$ and its length is $L$ and it is released from an angle $\theta_{0}$ from the vertical. We have to first find it's equation of motion. We can find it either by Newtonian Mechanics or by Lagrangain Mechanics or by using the energy method.
Total kinetic energy is 
$K=\frac{1}{2} mv^2$ or we can say that 
$dK=\frac{1}{2}\frac{m}{L}w^2 r^2 dr$
By doing all the calculations and then using that fact that total energy is constant, we get the equation of motion as
$$\frac{\textrm{d}\theta}{\textrm{d}t}=\sqrt{\dot{\theta_0}^2+\frac{3g}{L}(\cos(\theta_0)-\cos(\theta))}$$
The simple equation that we derive from Newton mechanics is just one more step applied to the above one.
$\frac{\textrm{d}^2\theta}{\textrm{d}t^2}-\frac{3g}{2L}\sin\theta=0$
So the time of fall is $$t=\int_{\theta_0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\dot{\theta_0}^2+\frac{3g}{L}(\cos(\theta_0)-\cos(\theta))}}\textrm{d}\theta$$
But here I am stuck. I can't evaluate the integral. Any help is greatly appreciated.
EDIT
We have $\dot{\theta_0}^2=0$ as $\theta_0$ is fixed. Now we have $$\frac{\textrm{d}\theta}{\textrm{d}t}=\sqrt{\frac{3g}{L}(\cos(\theta_0)-\cos(\theta))}$$
$$\implies \frac{\textrm{d}^2\theta}{\textrm{d}t^2}=\frac{1}{2\frac{\textrm{d}\theta}{\textrm{d}t}}×\frac{3g}{L}\cdot\sin\theta×\frac{\textrm{d}\theta}{\textrm{d}t}$$ $$\implies \frac{\textrm{d}^2\theta}{\textrm{d}t^2}-\frac{3g}{2L}\sin\theta=0$$

@AmrutAyan I guess we have to ignore the non ideal effects

Is your problem $\frac{\textrm{d}^2\theta}{\textrm{d}t^2}-\frac{3g}{2L}\sin\theta=0$ ?

@AmrutAyan it's 0...I'll edit my question to show that both the equations are same

@ClaudeLeibovici you can say that...but I didn't write the expression in that way cuz I wanna avoid second order differential equations (although I know how to solve them)

Its inverse is very simple. Don't you like Jacobi amplitude ?

@AmrutAyan i am so sorry...it's a typo

What do you mean by pointed? Can't It slip?

$I=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{k-\cos x}}\textrm{d}x$
From Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's book,
${I=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a-b\cos x}},dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a+b}}F\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)(1-\cos x)}{2(a-b\cos x)}}\right),\sqrt{\frac{2b}{a+b}}\right)}$,
Set $a=k, b=1$,
${I=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{k-\cos x}},dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+k}}F\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{(1+k)(1-\cos x)}{2(k-\cos x)}}\right),\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+k}}\right)}$

The answer should be "infinity". If it is really standing perfectly balanced, then there will be no force moving it out of this equilibrium, it stays standing upright and perfectly balanced. "Released from an angle" contradicts "perfectly balanced".

HINT:
Derivation is by considering KE/PE total energy conservation. Integrating we can better consider torque and moments. Torque equilibrium with respect to point of suspension is
$$ I \ddot \theta + mg L \sin \theta =0$$
$$ \frac13 m L^2 \ddot \theta + mg L/2 \sin \theta =0$$
$$ \ddot \theta + (3g /2L) \sin \theta =0$$
Traditionally for a pendulum $\theta$ is measured a vertical line below the fulcrum. This is because for a simple pendulum $\sin \theta $ can be approximated by $ \theta.$
Max PE is at $\theta =\pi $. Max KE is at $\theta =0 $. The ode is :
$\dfrac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\dfrac{3g}{2L}\sin\theta=0$
Boundary condition is $t=0,~ \theta=\theta_0= \pi ;$
This is a non-linear pendulum. $\sin \theta $ cannot be approximated by $ \theta$.
Solvable by (complete) elliptic integrals. Simulation of oscillations can be done.
EDIT1:
For the boundary conditions chosen the plus sign in (blue) ode results in to and fro full oscillations and for negative sign (red), practically an unmoving bob at the top position.. other initial conditions do not give regular periodic oscillations.


It should be mgL/2 sin theta...we consider the height of centre of mass of rod and not the highest point of rod

Your calculations are not correct imo...we have torque=force×distance and not torque+force×distance=0

Torque=I alpha or $$\tau =\frac{mL^2}{3}\cdot\frac{\textrm{d}^2\theta}{\textrm{d}t^2}$$ we also have $$\tau =mg\sin \theta \frac{L}{2}$$ we took $\frac{L}{2}\sin\theta$ as it is the length of the moment arm

Yes, thanks, we need to consider mass concentration at CG of rod.

@MathStackexchangeIsMarvellous: Sign in the ode is to be positive. We need to consider converging oscillations. Diverging oscillations may break the rod.

But physics says something else?? What is wrong in my approach?? Also see that by differentiating d theta/dt we obtain the equation that has a negative sign in it

$\ddot \theta+k \theta =0 $ leads to sine function oscillations. $\ddot \theta-k \theta =0$ leads to hyperbolic sine function oscillations.

That's okay...but according to physics there should be a negative sign in my opinion

Hey...if I consider that gravity is acting downwards so we have to take $-g$ to take care of the direction, then my formula becomes $\tau =-mg\sin \theta \frac{L}{2}$...and then it matches with your answer

I think the inclusion of elliptic functions adds little to the understanding of the problem, the most interesting case is when $\theta_0$ approaches zero.
This can be handled in elementary functions
Consider  an integral
$$ I=\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{cos(\theta_0)-\cos(\theta)}}$$
It is clear that the greatest contribution to the pendulum's falling time is made by movement near $\theta_0$, especially when $\theta_0$ is close to zero.
In this case we can use the first terms of the $\cos \theta$ taylor series:
$$\cos \theta\approx   1-\frac{\theta^2}{2}$$
The integral takes the form
$$ I\approx \int_{\theta_0}^{\theta}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\theta^2\ - \theta_0^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln\frac{\theta +\sqrt{\theta^2\ - \theta_0^2}}{\theta_0}$$
This approximation is more accurate the closer $\theta_0$ is to zero.
If we present the logarithm in the form
$$\ln\frac{\theta +\sqrt{\theta^2\ - \theta_0^2}}{\theta_0}=\ln  \left (\theta +\sqrt{\theta^2\ - \theta_0^2}  \right )+\ln \frac{1}{\theta_0}$$
then we see that the smaller $\theta_0$ is, the more the term $\ln \frac{1}{\theta_0}$ dominates.
Therefore, in the limiting case $\theta_0 \to 0$, the fall time is proportional to $\ln \frac{1}{\theta_0}$

"...the fall time is proportional to $\ln \frac{1}{\theta_0}$". Or more simply $-\ln \theta_0$.
